# trim string from first number in the string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the string "IX - Delivery Received 1/15/2018 9:34:00 AM " I want string like "IX - Delivery Received " in JavaScript.

I go long way  like

```
  var finalname = title.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
  var specialchar = finalname.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "");
```

which not work as expected.Actually I want to trim  when string contain first number. Could you please advice !!

Comment: You could do it the simple way and just iterate over the string until you find a number and use the index to take the substring

Comment: Find the index of the first number. Use `.slice()` from the start until that index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this,

```
var title = "IX - Delivery Received 1/15/2018 9:34:00 AM ";

var digit = title.search(/\d/);
var finalname = title.substring(0, digit);
```

Which outputs "IX - Delivery Received "

Answer (score 5):

Maybe split/join on the first number:

```js
let str = "IX - Delivery Received 1/15/2018 9:34:00 AM ";
let out = str.split(/\d/, 1).join().trim();
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Simple and fast. You might want to add a `.trim()`